Input "Submit" on Edit view is not working?
This is my code from view
@model ADF_Soft.Models.Multi_Models.Contragents_Countries_Roles_Categories

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";

}
<div class="col-xl-12">
    <!-- Account details card-->
    <div class="card m-4">
        <div class="card-header">Редактиране на контрагент</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form asp-action="Edit">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Contragent.ID" />
                <div class="row gx-3 mb-3">
                    <!-- Form Group (country)-->
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label asp-for="Contragent.Country_Code" class="small mb-1">Държава</label>
                        <select id="countryCode" class="form-select" asp-for="Contragent.Country_Code">
                            @foreach (var item in Model.ListOfCountries)
                            {
                                <option value="@item.Name">@item.Name</option>
                            }
                        </select>

                    </div>
                    <!-- Form Group (eik)-->
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label asp-for="Contragent.EIK" class="small mb-1">Булстат</label>
                        <input id="EIK" asp-for="Contragent.EIK" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Въведете булстат на фирмата" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Contragent.EIK" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Form Group (eik)-->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label asp-for="Contragent.VAT_Registration" class="control-label">Регистрация по ДДС*</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="customSwitch2" onclick="functionRegToVAT()">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Form Group (vat_number)-->
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label asp-for="Contragent.VAT_Number" class="small mb-1">ДДС номер</label>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm())
                        {
                            <input id="vat_number" asp-for="Contragent.VAT_Number" name="checkEIK" class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100" value="Зареди данни" asp-action="CreateVIES" />
                        }

                        <span asp-validation-for="Contragent.VAT_Number" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}

I'm having a problem with editing, when I try to edit something and hit the save button nothing happens, it doesn't go into the controller at all. Otherwise, it takes the counterparty's data, but I can't edit it.
I don't understand where I'm going wrong?

For starters, you're nesting forms in the snippet you shared. @Html.BeginForm creates a normal html5 in the markup. You can't nest forms.

Firstly you need make sure you are using asp.net core MVC or asp.net MVC, since the codes you are using is asp.net core's taghelper which is a asp.net core feature and this will not work inside ASP.NET.
If you want to make this edit form post to the specific controller's edit action like below, you could set the asp-action and asp-controller attribute.
Like this:
Controller:
 public class ContragentController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        ......
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(Contragents_Countries_Roles_Categories model)
    {
        .......
        return View(model);
    } 
}

Then the form tag will be like this:
        <form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Contragent" method="post">

But if you are using the ASP.NET MVC, then the taghelper will not work, since there is no tag helper inside the ASP.NET MVC, you should use the @Html.BeginForm instead. Please notice: the @Html.BeginForm could also work well inside  the asp.net core.
@Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Contragent" ,FormMethod.Post){
<div class="row gx-3 mb-3">
    .....
   </div>
}

Besides, you call Html.BeginForm method inside the <form> tag which makes the nested form tag. This will make the input submit don't know which is the form data and the target url, the right way to use this is put this input submit button inside the one form tag, it will automatically post the data to the form tag's url(/currentcontroller/edit action) and add this form's data.
Like below:
     <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Contragent.ID" />
            <div class="row gx-3 mb-3">
                <!-- Form Group (country)-->
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label asp-for="Contragent.Country_Code" class="small mb-1">Държава</label>
                    <select id="countryCode" class="form-select" asp-for="Contragent.Country_Code">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.ListOfCountries)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.Name">@item.Name</option>
                        }
                    </select>

                </div>
                <!-- Form Group (eik)-->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="Contragent.EIK" class="small mb-1">Булстат</label>
                    <input id="EIK" asp-for="Contragent.EIK" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Въведете булстат на фирмата" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Contragent.EIK" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- Form Group (eik)-->
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label asp-for="Contragent.VAT_Registration" class="control-label">Регистрация по ДДС*</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="customSwitch2" onclick="functionRegToVAT()">
                </div>
                <!-- Form Group (vat_number)-->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="Contragent.VAT_Number" class="small mb-1">ДДС номер</label>
                 
                        <input id="vat_number" asp-for="Contragent.VAT_Number" name="checkEIK" class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
                      
                    <span asp-validation-for="Contragent.VAT_Number" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>

